# AngularJS Cannot Set Property of Undefined

Tags: angularjs

Directive:

```
app.directive('myDialog', ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
  var fade = "fade";

  return {
    template: '<div ng-controller="AccountCtrl" ng-cloak="">' +
              '<div class="ui {{message.type}} message message-overwrite" ng-class="{'+ fade +': enabled} ">' +
              '<div class="header">{{message.title}}</div>' +
              '<p>{{message.content}}</p>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>',
    link: $timeout(function($scope) {
      $scope.enabled = true;
      console.log("Test");
    }, 1000)
  };
}]);
```

When trying to run my directive, I keep getting the error:

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot set property 'enabled' of undefined
```

But I'm not sure what the proper place to define 'enabled' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link function of a directive cannot be set to a `$timeout` if you want to access the scope. Angular invokes the link function and passes in `scope`, `element` and `attrs` in that order. So, when timeout is used, the inner function, which in your case thinks will be called by angular is not called. `$timeout` calls that. Not the directive. And that's why it's undefined.

What you could do to fix that is:

```
link: function($scope) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.enabled = true;
        console.log("Test");
    }, 1000);
}
```

So, move the timeout inside the link function. And of course you need to inject `$timeout` into the directive, which you already have.